# Solving $\begin{cases} z_1z_2=10\operatorname{cis}(\frac{4\pi}5)\\\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}^2}=\frac2{25}\operatorname{cis}(\frac{\pi}5)\end{cases}$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

> Solve
>   $$\begin{cases}z_1z_2=10(\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{5})\\\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}^2}=\frac{2}{25}(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{5})\end{cases}$$
>   over $\mathbb C$. The answer should be in trigonometric form. $z=a+ib$.

Let:
$$
z_1=r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)\\
z_2=r_2(\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2)\\
\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}^2}=\frac{z_1z_2^2}{\overline{z_2}^2z_2^2}=\frac{r_1r_2^2}{|z_2|^4}\stackrel{(\ast)}{=}\frac{r_1r_2^2}{r_2^4}=\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}
$$
then:
$$
\begin{cases}r_1r_2(\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2))=10(\cos\frac{4\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{5})\\[10pt]
\dfrac{r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)}{r_2^2(\cos2\theta_2+i\sin2\theta_2)}\stackrel{(\ast\ast)}{=}\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}(\cos(\theta_1+2\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1+2\theta_2))=\frac{2}{25}(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{5})\end{cases}
$$

According to De Moivre's rule we know that $z^n=r^n \operatorname{cis}(n\theta)$ but  in the transition $(\ast)$ why does $|z_2|^4=r_2^4$?

Lastly in the transition $(\ast\ast)$ is there some trig identity which leads to that?

Please **explain** the points $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$.

Comment: First, $\newcommand{\cis}{\text{cis}}|z^n|=|r^n\cis(n\theta)|=r^n|\cis(n\theta)|=r^n$. Second, $\dfrac{\cis(\theta)}{\cis(\psi)}=\cis(\theta-\psi)$, i.e it should be $\cos(\theta_1-2\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1-2\theta_2)$  and not as written.

Comment: @Galc127 in $|z^n|=r^n|cis(n\theta)|$ what happens with $|cis(n\theta)|$? Also confirming that it's $cis(\theta_1+2\theta_2)$

Comment: 1. $\newcommand{\cis}{\text{cis}}|\cis(n\theta)|=|\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)|=\sqrt{\cos^2(n\theta)+\sin^2(n\theta)}=1$.
2. It is $\cis(\theta_1+2\theta_2)$ because you have $$\frac{z_1}{\bar{z_2}^2}=\frac{r_1\cis(\theta_1)}{r_2^2\cis(-2\theta_2)}=\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}\cis(\theta_1+2\theta_2)$$ The solution missed the fact that it is $\bar{z_2}$ in denominator...

Comment: The general relation you want is $(a ~\cis~ b) \times (c ~\cis~ d) = ( (ab) ~\cis~ (c + d))$.  This isn't a consequence of demoivre's , but rather demoivre is a special case of the above relation, which can be proven with straightforward angle sum formulas.  Demoivre is actually pretty irrelevant to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r_1r_2=10$ and $\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}=\frac{2}{25}$, which gives $r_1=2$ and $r_2=5$.

Let $z_1=2cis\theta_1$ and $z_2=5cis\theta_2$.

Thus, $\theta_1+\theta_2=\frac{4\pi}{5}+2\pi k$ and $\theta_1+2\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{5}+2\pi m$, where $\{k,m\}\subset\mathbb Z$.

Finally we obtain: $\theta_1=\theta_2=\frac{7\pi}{5}$

Your $*$ is true by the De Moivre's rule.

Your $**$ is true because $\frac{cis\theta}{cis\phi}=cis(\theta-\phi)$ and $\overline{cis\theta}=cis(-\theta)$.

$\frac{cis\theta}{cis\phi}=cis(\theta-\phi)$ because
$$\frac{cis\theta}{cis\phi}=\frac{cis\theta\overline{cis\phi}}{cis\phi\overline{cis\phi}}=cis(\theta-\phi)=$$

Comment: Please read the last line in the OP. I want to understand the points $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$, I know the final answer.

Comment: @Yos I fixed. See now.

Comment: Why is $\frac{cis\theta_1}{cis\theta_2}=cis(\theta_1-\theta_2)$? Is there an identity for that?

Comment: @Yos Because $cis(\theta_1-\theta_2)cis\theta_2=(\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2))(\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2)=\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1=cis\theta_1$.

Comment: How do you get to $cis(\theta_1-\theta_2)cis\theta_2$? Can you please show the development from the fraction $\frac{cis\theta_1}{cis\theta_2}$?

Comment: @Yos See now please.

Comment: Ok but initially we have $\frac{\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1}{\cos 2\theta_2+i\sin 2\theta_2}$? Then we decide to multiply the fraction by $\frac{\cos 2\theta_2-i\sin 2\theta_2}{\cos 2\theta_2-i\sin 2\theta_2}$ right?

Comment: @Yos Yes, but I think it's better to use the rule: $\frac{cis\theta}{cis\phi}=cis(\theta-\phi)$

Comment: So why is everyone saying that this is wrong that $\ast\ast$ equality is wrong?

Comment: @Yos It was his mistake, I think.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether the stages $\ast$ and $\ast\ast$ are mistakes? egreg claims they are

Comment: @Yos I think your work is right.

Answer (score 2):

The line where you have $(*)$ should better be
$$
\left|\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}^{\,2}}\right|=
\frac{|z_1|}{\bigl|\overline{z_2}^{\,2}\bigr|}=\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}
$$
There is no reason for the equality *before* the one you mark with $(*)$.

The equality you mark with $({*}{*})$ is indeed wrong and it should be
$$
\frac{r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)}{r_2^2(\cos2\theta_2-i\sin2\theta_2)}=\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}(\cos(\theta_1+2\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1+2\theta_2))=\frac{2}{25}(\cos\frac{\pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{5})
$$
because if $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, then $\bar{z}=r(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)$. Next apply the standard rules
\begin{gather}
\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^{-1}\\[4px]
(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)(\cos\beta+i\sin\beta)=
\cos(\alpha+\beta)+i\sin(\alpha+\beta)
\end{gather}

---

#### Further notes.

The equality
$$
\frac{z_1z_2^2}{\overline{z_2}^{\,2}z_2^2}=\frac{r_1r_2^2}{|z_2|^4}
$$
is generally false, because there's no reason for $z_1z_2^2$ to be real.

When you expand $\dfrac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}^{\,2}}$, you should write
$$
\frac{r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)}
{\bigl(\overline{r_2(\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2}\bigr)^2}
=
\frac{r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)}
{(r_2(\cos\theta_2-i\sin\theta_2)^2}
=
\frac{r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)}
{r_2^2(\cos2\theta_2-i\sin2\theta_2)}
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why $\ast\ast$ equality is a mistake? As far as I understand we have $$\frac{\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1}{\cos 2\theta_2+i\sin 2\theta_2}=\frac{(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)(\cos 2\theta_2-i\sin 2\theta_2)}{(\cos 2\theta_2+i\sin 2\theta_2)(\cos 2\theta_2-i\sin 2\theta_2)}=...$$

Comment: @Yos In the denominator there is $\overline{z_2}^{\,2}$, not $z_2^2$.

Comment: yes but I'm referring to the result of this: $$\frac{z_1}{\overline{z_2}^2}=\frac{z_1z_2^2}{\overline{z_2}^2z_2^2}=\frac{r_1r_2^2}{|z_2|^4}\stackrel{(\ast)}{=}\frac{r_1r_2^2}{r_2^4}=\frac{r_1}{r_2^2}\Rightarrow \frac{r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)}{r_2^2(\cos 2\theta_2+i\sin 2\theta_2)}$$

Comment: @Yos If you start from a wrong equality, you get nothing good, do you? It is *false* that $z_1z_2^2=r_1r_2^2$. The “solution” has two gross errors; the final result is correct, but just by chance.

Comment: Thanks for the additional note in the answer!

Comment: @Yos Still I don't understand why you mark as correct an answer that glosses over the clear mistakes in the source.

Comment: I feel this is beyond my knowledge to determine whether mistakes are present and what they are exactly. The author of the answer claims there're no mistakes, so third party who's way more knowledgeable than me has to decide.

Comment: @Yos The author of the answer is not humble enough to acknowledge his/her mistakes. The equality I pointed to (the one before your $(*)$) is silly. And so is the plus sign in the denominator where a minus sign should have been.